# Error on Ajax in ASP MVC 4

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

i have an asp mvc 4 app and i have the next problem:

I have an Ajax call to an ActionResult in controller:

```
function SetMark() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=Url.Action("SelectMark", "Home")%>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {anio:$("#anio").val()},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#marca").html(data);
            }

        });
    }
```

And controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult SelectMark(string anio)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            tarifData.dataTable = GetMarks(anio);

            return PartialView("_Marca", tarifData);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

In localhost working properly, but in server (server 2008 r2) all ajax calls returns a 500 error.

anyone has any idea of the problem? Repeat, in localhost working properly.

Comment: A 500 error is usually the result of an exception in the controller. You need to post your method for `SelectMark()`

Comment: Only thing that looks like it could be a problem is your method `GetMarks()`

Comment: Where do you initialize `tarifData`? (have you omitted some code?)

Comment: Get marks connect with database and return data

Comment: Initialice:  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
       
        TarifDataViewModel tarifData = new TarifDataViewModel();

Comment: Edit your question with updated code (difficult to read in comments). I suggest you comment out `tarifData.dataTable = GetMarks(anio);` (or populate it with some hardcoded values) and see if you still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Specify `dataType:"html"` in ajax request as shown.

```
function SetMark() {
    $.ajax({
         url: '<%=Url.Action("SelectMark", "Home")%>',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType:'html',
         data: {anio:$("#anio").val()},
         success: function (data) {
             $("#marca").html(data);
         }
    });
}
```